# How to browse the localhost on android device?

Tags: android, apache, web-services, tomcat8

I try to browse localhost on my samsung device. I connected my device with eclipse via wifi. browsing http://192.1.1.190 I get a "Page not avialable. I remember, some days ago it worked

but on the emulator I am able to browse localhost.

I searched on google not able to find the correct ideas.can any one know about this.

any ideas? regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device for answers.

Comment: well USB isnt gonna create a network just connect over wifi

Comment: What do you have in mind when you talk about browsing a localhost? And further: Every pc or android device is its own localhost. So about which one are you talking?

Comment: `on the emulator I am able to browse localhost.` ??? Please tell what you do and what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building an Android app on the side and struggled with this problem.  One solution here would be to connect your Android phone to a WiFi network which your Android Studio is also connected.

Then, when you debug your app from Android Studio, the phone should be able to access the IP address corresponding to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i connect android device with wifi.but my laptop wifi ip and device ip is showing different ip numbers.so i cant able to access the localhost on android device especially.

Comment: Please why are you posting this info as an answer. You should put info in your post. Edit your post. Or put extra info in a comment. Further: what you said makes no sense. Of course every device has a different ip address. In that way you can address each device.